# Django Rest Framework - AssertionError Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return a single object specific to a user (not a queryset), without having to specify an identifier/pk within the requested URL. Each user has an organisation FK.

i.e. `http://website/organisation` and not `http://website/organisation/1`

I'm receiving the following error, since it's expecting this identifier:

`AssertionError: Expected view OrganisationDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "user__organisation_id". Fix your URL conf, or set the .lookup_field attribute on the view correctly.`

**How/What do I need to specify when using the RetrieveModelMixin/GenericAPIView so that it returns a singular object linked by a FK?**

My view class:

```
class OrganisationDetail(
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView
):
    serializer_class = OrganisationDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk' # I know this is the default and there's no need to specify

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Organisation.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.organisation_id)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Related URL:

```
url(r'^api/v1/organisation/$', OrganisationDetail.as_view()),
```

My model:

```
class Person(AbstractUser):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(
        Organisation, related_name='members', null=True
    )
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + " - " + self.email
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to override `get_object()`, not `get_queryset()` for detail views. You still want the permission checking so I suggest going through the source. First remove your `get_queryset()` method then try this for starters:

```
# inside OrganisationDetail
queryset = Organisation.objects.all()

def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    # make sure to catch 404's below
    obj = queryset.get(pk=self.request.user.organisation_id)
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

Comment: Can anyone explain me what does this line do? queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

Comment: This answer is for the use-case of the poster which is to return only one object. It won't work for your use-case which returns multiple objects. You'll need to ask a separate question and detail your problem there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mixins, change the lookup_field to the right one

```
class OrganisationDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = OrganisationDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'members' 

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change a parameter, it had id, instead of pk in the path that should only show one element, when changing it to <int: pk>, it has worked wonderfully

```py
from the django.urls import path
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from posts import views


urlpatterns = [
    path ('posts /', views.PublicationList.as_view ()),
    path ('posts / <int: id> /', views.Publication_detail.as_vi`enter code here`ew ()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns (urlpatterns)
```

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)